# How to disable a form element in symfony?

Tags: php, forms, symfony1

I am using a Select element, in form

```
'country' =>new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => CountryPeer::getAllCountry())),

'city' =>new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => CityPeer::getAllCity())),
```

i want that city element to be disabled, at the first time when the page loads. and on selection of country the city element will be enabled.(it will be loaded through AJAX call)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable like this

> $this->widgetSchema['country']->setAttribute('disabled',
>   'disabled');

Comment: Yeah! This works the select option is disabled at first time when the form loads. thanks Metoikos!

Comment: As Mike already mentioned. This is not the right way when you want to use the fields for POST/PUT later on. Then it should be readonly instead of disabled

Answer (score 6):

$this->widgetSchema['field']->setAttribute('readonly', 'readonly');

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will try this and let you know as ->setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); worked for me.

Comment: This is the correct way. If you set to disabled and submit the form, and form does not pass validation, any widgets set to disabled will not be reloaded. Setting to readonly worked in my sitch.

Comment: I agree that this is the correct way. Setting the attribute to disabled meant that if another field failed validation, the value for the disabled form field would not be repopulated.  Readonly ftw.

Comment: Disable didn't work for me (disabled value wasn't saved). With read only it works perfectly. Thanks for your tips. David

Answer (score 0):

If you already load the data of the second list via AJAX, why don't you disable and enable the second list via Javascript?

The disabling could be done either hardcoded in the template (with plain HTML) or done by Javascript (after document load).

For the enabling, use a callback method for the AJAX call (on the success event).

It would be could to know, how you actually do the AJAX call (jquery?).

Answer (score 0):

Well, most clean way is to learn "how to write your own widget" and actually write it. You can take a look at `sfWidgetFormDate` as a rough example.